# Apache Karaf instance opens lot of random unknown ports

Tags: apache-karaf

I have come across this issue where after starting the karaf instance few random ports get opened and after sometime frequency of the opening of this random ports increases. I'm wondering what could be the reason for opening these many ports or how could I debug this issue.

Below is the result from netstat :

```
 
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID      

  TCP    127.0.0.1:63062        127.0.0.1:63063        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63063        127.0.0.1:63062        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63064        127.0.0.1:63065        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63065        127.0.0.1:63064        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63066        127.0.0.1:63067        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63067        127.0.0.1:63066        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63068        127.0.0.1:63069        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63069        127.0.0.1:63068        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63083        127.0.0.1:63084        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63084        127.0.0.1:63083        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63085        127.0.0.1:63086        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63086        127.0.0.1:63085        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63087        127.0.0.1:63088        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63088        127.0.0.1:63087        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63089        127.0.0.1:63090        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63090        127.0.0.1:63089        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63091        127.0.0.1:63092        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63092        127.0.0.1:63091        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63093        127.0.0.1:63094        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63094        127.0.0.1:63093        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63095        127.0.0.1:63096        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63096        127.0.0.1:63095        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63097        127.0.0.1:63098        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63098        127.0.0.1:63097        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63099        127.0.0.1:63100        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63100        127.0.0.1:63099        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63101        127.0.0.1:63102        ESTABLISHED     22488
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63102        127.0.0.1:63101        ESTABLISHED     22488
```

Comment: looks like it's connecting to itself. Is it fresh instance of Karaf? Which version?

Comment: Karaf version is 4.0.3 and it is not a fresh instance. I have added features of camel, jmx, custom features , etc

Comment: so looks like something inside the karaf (but not karaf itself) opens the listening and normal sockets